# Includegraphics error - "PDF contains invalid UTF-8 characters"?

Tags: pgfplots, errors, pdf, matlab2tikz, includegraphics

I have a PDF figure (a `PGFplot` created by `matlab2tikz`). However, when I include it in my LaTeX document (using `\includegraphics`, I get loads of errors complaining

> String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.

What might be the problem here? The PDF figure opens correctly in a variety of PDF viewers. Only TeX seems to have a problem with it.

The plot below was typeset using `pdflatex` with the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[sb]{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4} % inconsolata for mono, not LibertineMono
\usepackage{amsthm} % libertinust1math loads amsmath
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,babel} % babel is needed to avoid incompatibilities with onlyamsmath
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize[optimize=false]
\newcommand{\includetikz}[1]{%
    \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}%
    \input{#1.tikz}%
}

\begin{document}
\centering
\includetikz{ce_at_cc}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following plot and writes to the file `ce_at_cc.pdf` successfully.

Later on in a **different** document which is to be compiled using `luatex` , I try to include this graphic with `\includegraphics{ce_at_cc.pdf}` and it produces the aforementioned error (actually a whole bunch of same repeated error message). I am using TL2018.

Comment: latex shouldn't care about the content of a pdf, but the file name could be a problem. Your reference of matlab2tikz could also mean that there is an intermediary tex-file involved. In that case checks its file encoding and if neeeded reencode it to utf8.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't understand what is wrong with my filename. ```ce_at_cc_1Cdischg.pdf``` is the name of the file containing the figure I am trying to use using ```\includegraphics```

Comment: I didn't say that your file name is wrong. It is only one of the possibilities. You are not giving enough information so the best one can do is guessing.  If you can't give more details this site here is the wrong place to ask for help.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Alright. I have included more information. Sorry that I didn't know how much detail to post in a public forum. I think that this could be ```luatex``` bug?

Comment: As I suspected: you are not using \includegraphics but \includetikz. Check the encoding of `ce_at_cc.tikz`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The ```\includetikz``` is in a separate file, which is processed and produces a stand-alone PDF. The ```\includegraphics``` is in a separate document which includes this in my desired document. There are 2 latex files involved - a) for processing tikz to pdf and b) the document where the PDF is included.

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce your problem with your snippets. Find someone you can show all the files involved.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer alas. There is no one in my group who uses latex. Can you please take a look? I have posted the ```tikz``` source code [here](https://gist.github.com/krishnakumarg1984/77573995777d0d2866318cd1c185f77e). It successfully produces the PDF. But when including this PDF in a luatex document, it throws up error.

Comment: No problem here. Show a small but complete example of the luatex document which throws the error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I found out the issue. It was a path issue on my local machine. I had accidentally a zero-size file of the same name in the root of the project directory. Sorry for all the bother.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the (local) issue is just a zero-size forgotten file.